# Convert an excel column containing both hr:min:sec and min:sec to hr:min:sec format

Tags: excel

```
25:01:00
24:43:00
23:34
22:52
```

I have values like these in an excel column. Is there a ways to select all while retaining the hr:min:sec and changing the min:sec to the hr:min:sec format? I have tried to change the format but this has not worked.

Comment: I would use an if() counting the ":" and doing one conversion for H:M:S and if false converting the M:S but adding H:.

Comment: Or just the length of string...

Comment: Do you have any sources on how to do this? I am not well-versed in excel.

Comment: LEN() will give you the number of characters in the string, so if 5 or less convert M:S and add hours otherwise a full convert.

Comment: Hi @Blacklivesmatter can you clarify the qustion a little please? You want to put these into a new column with formatting `hh:mm:ss` or just change the formatting of the data in the existing location in the sheet? thanks

Comment: Hello. I would like to just change the format of the existing column location to hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure how you get your data but hopefully there is enough here to help you figure it out even if I dont quite understand everything in your question.

If you are highlighting the cells and setting the custom number format to "[hh]:mm:ss" and nothing is happening (e.g. `22:42` stays unchanged rather than seeing `22:42:00`) then it is probably because the contents of the cell are a string not a number.

Date format (any number formats) will only change the look of a numeric value. Remember underlyign a date is stored as a number: whole number part is days and fraction is part of a day, so `1.25` is one day and a quarter: formatting 1.25 as `[hh]:mm:dd` will give you `30:00:00` (note square brackets give you the total hours, not the hour in the day so 1.25 formatted `hh:mm:ss` will give you `06:00:00` - 1 day 6 hours but the format supresses the day)

So you need to get/confirm the cell contents to be a number and then formatting the cell with a custom format of `"[hh]:mm:ss"` will get you to where you want to be. There may be some stray spaces or something that is forcing the value to stay as a string rather than a number.

Either edit the cells to make the string a value (select the cell/F2/return will convert a numeric-parseable string to a number) or use the `value` function on each cell - this will take any string that can be parsed to a number and convert it from a string to a number

e.g. `value("30:00:00")` = `1.25` which can then be formatted with the custom number format `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: I think that I was unclear. When I change the custom format to [hh]:mm:ss, the result is inaccurate. For example, 23:34 would turn into 23:34:00

Comment: what do you expect to see in this example?

Comment: 23:34 to 00:23:34

Comment: That is not possible with formatting. Remember a format is just a different window to view a number: `23:34` is actually the number `0.981944444` and `00:23:34` is actually the number `0.016365741` - so to achieve what you want to you will need a formula to transform the starting number.

Comment: Thank you all! I think I will import this into R and use gsub to fix it. I will report back after I attempt.

Comment: the numbers are hh:mm:ss (time elapsed). The numbers that are present can be with 9:00:00, 11:00:00. or 22:00 if they do not reach 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

So the values you got are actually minutes and seconds, just divide by 60:

[image]

The formula I've used in column B is `=A1/60` and drag down. Then I applied format [hh]:mm:ss.

So 23:34 will get converted to 00:23:34

Comment: So, the numbers are hh:mm:ss (time elapsed). The numbers that are present can be with 9:00:00, 11:00:00. or 22:00 if they do not reach 1 hour.